# Array.splice() not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm having a issue with the `Array.splice()` function. When I add an object to an array, then splice it back out, it loses all its properties. Why?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WuPjV/1/).

```
// create a new object named myObj, test to see if all properties are intact
var myObj = {
    prop1: 5,
    prop2: 3,
    prop3: 9
};

for(key in myObj) {
    document.write(key + " <br>");
}

// they are, prepare a break-line
document.write("---<br>");    

// okay, so I'm adding the object to a newly created array
var myArr = new Array();
myArr.push(myObj);

// watch what happens if I splice the obj back out of the array
var mySplicedObj = myArr.splice(0, 1);

// why doesn't this work?
document.write(mySpliceObj.prop1);

// this shows that myObj has lost all its properties when spliced!
for(key in mySplicedObj) {
    document.write(key);
}

// how is this happening, and why?
​
```

Comment: Please post your code here so we don't need to go to another link. I've moved it for you.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Sorry about that. I just thought somebody might want to see a working version of it.

Comment: You wrote `mySplicedObj` on one line and then `mySpliceObj` on another.

Comment: I suppose I did at that. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: Working demos are nice too, but the link should be supplementary. In other words, the question should contain enough information so that if the link ever breaks, the question will still be useful. :)

Comment: Ah, good point. I'll keep that in mind for the next time I ask a question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`splice()` returns an array, you can access the object by using `mySplicedObj[0]`.

Comment: Oh, really? W3School's Javascript manual didn't reveal that, and neither did any of my Google or SO searches. Thanks!

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: Don't use w3schools as a source (http://w3fools.com/), check out Mozilla's JS Docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: Use `console.log` to check out what was returned by `Array.splice`.

Comment: Ooh, handy. I sure will. Thanks *again*.